# Two way SSL with Chromecast

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I want to implement two way SSL with Chromecast (It will be my receiver and my sender app).

1) Is two way SSL possible with Chromecast ?

2) What certificates I can use ?

3) Do I need to get/purchase certs from Google ?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to do?

Comment: The objective is to play the content from our content server and make sure only known/authentic clients be allowed the access the protected resource on our server with Mutual SSL(Two way SSL).

Comment: If any client requests any content  to my server I want to be sure that its a Chromecast and not any client imitating as Chromecast.

Comment: @GopalkrishnaMudaliar did you find a way to do this? we would like to do the same but can't find any documentations regarding this

Comment: @grgmo I couldn't do two way SSL for some limits. But for that you need to get the Google cert and add that in your server so then it sends your server will be able to authenticate it.

Comment: SSLServerSocket ss = null;
<br>ss.setUseClientMode(false);
<br>/*Request the Cient for certs/authentication. If set to true,   and client chooses not to provide authentication information about itself, the negotiations will continue */
<br>ss.setWantClientAuth(false);

 <br>/*Request the Client for certs/authentication. If set to true,  Client must send its certs, else the negotiations will stop  and the connection will be dropped */
<br>ss.setNeedClientAuth(false);
            return ss;
        }

Comment: @GopalkrishnaMudaliar did you get the cert from Google? what's the process behind this?

Comment: @grgmo   I got cert from a CA but not from Google. I used that cert in my server. This is one way SSL.

Comment: @GopalkrishnaMudaliar if you don't mind could you point me what provider you used and how you implemented this?

Comment: @grgmo 1) I used GoDaddy certs.

Comment: @grgo 1) I converted that to .p12 format and bundled in my /asset/ folder of my Android App. 2) When I create a SSL socket factory for my server app i read the p12 from my asset.